# pandas read_json reads large integers as strings incorrectly

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to read tweets which are stored as json files. I'm using pandas to load the data. But found some strange behaviour in the `read_json` function. It I'm providing an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) below:

```
json_content="""
{ 
    "1": {
        "tid": "9999999999999998", 
    }, 
    "2": {
        "tid": "9999999999999999", 
    },
    "3": {
        "tid": "10000000000000001", 
    },
    "4": {
        "tid": "10000000000000002", 
    }
}
"""
df=pd.read_json(json_content,
                orient='index', # read as transposed
                convert_axes=False, # don't convert keys to dates
        )
print(df.info())
print(df)
```

Which outputs the following on my PC:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 4 entries, 1 to 4
Data columns (total 1 columns):
tid    4 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1)
memory usage: 64.0+ bytes
None
                 tid
1   9999999999999998
2  10000000000000000
3  10000000000000000
4  10000000000000002
```

> Which is not storing the correct values for `tid` column, why is this
>   happening?

**Note:** There shouldn't be [an overflow case](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18842). The `tid` column is being stored as int64, which has a limit about 10 times higher than the tid I originally tested with(see below):

```
import sys
# original problem 
tid_0 = 956677215197970432 
print(sys.maxsize,tid_0,sys.maxsize/tid_0)    # < 1 if overflow possible
# minimal case
tid = 10000000000000001 
print(sys.maxsize,tid,sys.maxsize/tid)    # < 1 if overflow possible

#Output
9223372036854775807 956677215197970432 9
9223372036854775807 10000000000000001 922
```

**Update** :

> It is reading correctly on explictly specifying the argument
>   `dtype=int`, but I don't understand why. What changes when we specify
>   the dtype?

Comment: Filed an issue for the same: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20608

Answer (score 2):

you can specify a dtype explicitly:

```
In [32]: df=pd.read_json(json_content,
    ...:                 orient='index', # read as transposed
    ...:                 convert_axes=False, # don't convert keys to dates
    ...:                 dtype='int64'   # <------- NOTE
    ...:         )
    ...: print(df.info())
    ...: print(df)
    ...:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 4 entries, 1 to 4
Data columns (total 1 columns):
tid    4 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1)
memory usage: 64.0+ bytes
None
                 tid
1   9999999999999998
2   9999999999999999
3  10000000000000001
4  10000000000000002
```

it also works as expected if we specify integers instead of string values in JSON:

```
In [61]: %paste
json_content="""
{
    "1": {
        "tid": 9999999999999998,
    },
    "2": {
        "tid": 9999999999999999,
    },
    "3": {
        "tid": 10000000000000001,
    },
    "4": {
        "tid": 10000000000000002,
    }
}
"""

df=pd.read_json(json_content,
                orient='index', # read as transposed
                convert_axes=False, # don't convert keys to dates
        )
print(df.dtypes)
print(df)

## -- End pasted text --
tid    int64
dtype: object
                 tid
1   9999999999999998
2   9999999999999999
3  10000000000000001
4  10000000000000002
```

so it looks like it has to do with type inference, because per default `dtype=True`, which means: `If True, infer dtypes`

Comment: thanks for the info. I was looking for an explanation to the behavior as well. I happened to find that explicitly mentioning dtype works just before you posted. This is a workaround, but it isn't answering my question. (The downvote you just got isn't from me)

Comment: @UdayrajDeshmukh, it has something to do with the type inferring - if you pass integers instead of strings (example: `"tid": 10000000000000002` instead of `"tid": "10000000000000002"`) - it'll work properly. PS default  `dtype-True` - `"If True, infer dtypes"`

Comment: Actually I'm reading it from about 100 json files (A sample of twitter database), which already have the tid column as strings

Comment: @UdayrajDeshmukh, yeah, i'm trying to find a reason for this - it seems to be a "type inference"